# Python: List all prime numbers that exist before an input number

Tags: python, loops, numbers, nested

```
n= int(raw_input("Number? "))
for x in range (2, n+1): 
    for y in range (2, x+1):
    if x < n+1 and x % 2.0 > 0 and x % 3.0 > 0 and x%y > 0:
            print x
            x = x + 1
```

Hello there. I need to create a SIMPLE python program, which lists all the prime numbers up to and inclusive of the input number. For example, if you input 10, it would produce 2, 3, 5 ,7

I'd prefer to keep it simple, and do not use more advanced functions such as def, break. Nested loops are PREFERED.

The code above does NOT work, it contains non-primes such as 25 and 91.

Please help!

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/353278

Comment: Why shoud it work ? You are printing a number as soon as it is not a multiple of 2 nor 3 !

Answer (score 2):

Your code concludes that a number `x` is prime if it's not divisible by *at least one* `y`, whereas it needs to check that it's not divisible by *all* `y`.

You also need to carefully check the bounds of the `y` loop.

On a side note, I suggest you get rid of the floating-point calculations (e.g. `x % 2.0`) and stick to integer maths. It *probably* doesn't matter here, but has the potential of opening a large can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

You must reverse your thinking. Your code reports a number as soon as it is a non-multiple of some y. Instead, you should **non-report** a number as soon as it is a **multiple** of some y.

```
n= int(raw_input("Number? "))
for x in range (2, n + 1):
    prime= True
    for y in range (2, x):
        if x % y == 0:
            prime= False
    if prime:
        print x
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying Daoust. Problem is, I don't know how to fix it. And no, this is NOT a duplicate. I am not allowed to use any advanced function in Python. I can only use functions like while loop, for loop, isprime, math.sqrt etc.

Comment: Don't shout at me, the comment about duplicate was from someone else.